# Issue with mouse move event

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, wpf-controls

I have a WPF control1 (has a moving control) that is hosted through elementhost on a windows form. My aim is to capture the mouse move events for the elementhost.

I found out from the following link that MouseMove fires when Control moves under mouse while mouse stands still.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/56e7b331-ac6f-4d62-a83b-c09009b79fa0

I am getting fake mouse move events for elementhost. In order to fix this issue, I added a button on top of elementhost and set its Visible property to Hidden. Still I get fake mouse move events.. How to fix this issue? Is there any workaround?

Appreciate your help...

Comment: if you edit your question for the 8th time, it may turn into community wiki. Beware!!! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your mousemove event, log down the values of e.X and e.Y, keeping your mouse stationary. If they're the same, the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed this issue in a WPF app without ElementHost - mousemove fires continually for a stationary mouse!! I'm now putting an intermediary class between the publisher and subscriber to filter the events if a duplicate X & Y point comes through (plus decouple subscribers from MouseEventArgs so I can unit test subscribers)